# Create list of interval times given start and stop time

Tags: python, list, time

Given string Start and Stop dates/times and number of intervals by which I want to count the time in between:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta    
Start = '16 Sep 2016 00:00:00' 
Stop= '16 Sep 2016 06:00:00.00'
ScenLength = 21600 # in seconds (21600 for 6 hours; 18000 for 5 hours; 14400 for 4 hours)
stepsize = 10 # seconds
Intervals = ScenLength/stepsize
```

how do I create a list of those dates and times?

I am new to Python and don't have much so far:

```
TimeList=[]    
TimeSpan = [datetime.datetime.strptime(Stop,'%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')-datetime.datetime.strptime(Start,'%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')]     
    for m in range(0, Intervals):
        ...
        TimeList.append(...)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to find time stamps in a regular interval.

That can be done with the Python class [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.strptime('16 Sep 2016 00:00:00', '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
stop = datetime.datetime.strptime('16 Sep 2016 06:00:00', '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')

stepsize = 10
delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=stepsize)

times = []
while start < stop:
    times.append(start)
    start += delta

print( times )
```

*edit*: complete example